# container element not displaying correctly in chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
  #container{
        border: 5px solid white;
        
        width: 100%; /* set canvas width to 100% */
        min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        box-shadow: 5px 3px 2px 2px  white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        
      }
```

working fine in Firefox Mobile on my mobile and all the devices in Chrome DevTools.
[chrome mobile][1]    [firefox mobile][2]

When I try to adjust the height of the container to be able to fit in Chrome Mobile, the view in Firefox and all the devices in Chrome DevTools will be messed up.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the description of your problem "will be messed up" is not clear. Be careful using viewport units for height as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veEqYQlfNx8